# How can i get the view of anyScreen programatically wherever i am present at the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

**How can i Get View From that corresponding Screen Programatically **

```
How can i get the view of screen programatically wherever i am present at the screen. Is it possible,And if yes send me some notes.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very poorly worded. Do you want to take a screenshot of the screen? Please explain better (or give an example) of what you want to do and where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
View newView = this.getView();
```

Let me know if this helps.